# Kombucha starter: minimum quantity for successful brew?

Tags: kombucha

I recently bought a 3 gallon fermentation vessel which came with a scoby package that said it's good for one gallon. Do I need to use 3 of the scoby packages or will one do with just a little extra fermentation time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More time is fine. Due to growth rates, if you use only 1 pack then you will need  approximatley  2.5 times as long in the fermnter.